# nyc(istanbul) reporters are hiding the reasons for test failures

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, istanbul

I am testing my JS code with mocha, however I am not able to see the error report(reasons for errors) in command prompt 
when I use reporters of istanbul.

If I use a below command I am getting the error report.

```
"nyc mocha test/testSetup.js \"test/**/*.test.js\""
```

If I use below command I am not getting the error report.

```
"nyc report --reporter=lcov --reporter=text mocha test/testSetup.js \"test/**/*.test.js\""
```

Please suggest the exact command where I can get error report, command line coverage report and html coverage report.

Comment: If you have istanbul and mocha install why not just run `istanbul cover _mocha`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nyc mocha --reporter spec test/testSetup.js \"test/**/*.test.js\""
```